# Hot to get a Geojson string from entity?

Tags: entity-framework-core, geospatial, npgsql, nettopologysuite

```
public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Geometry Location { get; set; }
}
```

My entity framework entity `City` type has a `Geometry` property. I am getting data like following:

```
public class CitiesController {

   public Task<IActionResult> Get(){
       var nearbyCities = context.Cities
                  .Where(c => c.Location.Distance(somePoint) < 100);

       response OK(??? geojson string ???);
   }
}
```

So I want how can I get Geojson string using Npgsql or Nettopologysuite?

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to use the [NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON): pass the NetTopologySuite objects you get from the database to GeoJsonSerializer.

[Here are some decent-looking examples](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/NetTopologySuite.IO/GeoJsonSerializer/-/php-geojsonserializer-class-examples.html).